# Java Regex ORing

Tags: mysql, regex

I have my query pattern as `"^(select (skip \\d+)? (first \\d+))"`. 
I would like to match queries of type

```
1."SELECT * FROM X"
2."SELECT SKIP a FIRST b * FROM X"
3."SELECT SKIP a * FROM X"
4."SELECT FIRST B * FROM X"
```

The above regex i tried works fine for 1,2,3 but not for 4. 
Any ideas to what i should change the regex, so that all 4 patterns can be queried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^select (?:skip \d+\s+)?(?:first \d+\s+)?\* from X$
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oF9hR9/7

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to match all of these entries:

```
select\s*(?:skip\s*\d+)?\s*(?:first\s*\d+)?(?:\s*\*?\s*from\s+\d+)?
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xI5gI1/3)